# Selenium driver.get does't load the page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I'm using `webdriver-manager` for managing chrome drivers as follows:

```py
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
driver.get('http://localhost:1234')
```

It seems initially to work and the browser spawns a window, but it remain on `data:,` tab and the `driver.get` doesn't work. Anyone faced the same problem?

`5.19.0-38-generic #39~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 21:16:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

chromium installed version: `112.0.5615.49 (Official build) snap (a 64 bit)`

From snap.

Installed pip dependencies:

```
webdriver-manager
selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `WebDriverManager` any more if you are using selenium `v4.6.0` or above. With `v4.6.0` selenium has introduced [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/). Essentially `SeleniumManager` will do the job of managing drivers for you.

You can replace the below line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
```

To:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

**UPDATE:** If you are specific about using `WebDriverManager`, my hunch is that you are using selenium `v4.8.1` or lower, if yes, just update your selenium to `v4.8.3`