# Selenium Junit maven - vulnerable dependency error?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

Normally I use a windows computer and these settings are working for me well without problem. But I am currently using MacBook pro (intel i9) and getting this error. I can't able to work junit. Can anyone help me please?

[image]

When I try to run a basic test getting errors Webdriver doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76003340/7598774

Comment: I need to solve that problem before everything because I have projects. :(

Comment: Are you particular about using `WebDriverManager`? Or are you ok to not use it?

Comment: If possible I would like to use WebDriverManager but if there is no change I can try something new :(  This is a very important problem for me atm. I don't have much time. That completely comes to me strange. 5-6 months before I used it without problem.

Comment: Can you share the complete error stack trace from your console into your question?

Comment: Which error? dependency error or test error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253130/discussion-between-shawn-and-baris-can-ates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If below is the error you see in your console:

```
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
```

Then just change the selenium version from `v4.8.1` to `v4.8.3` in your POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```